# How do I use inspection to retrieve a list of sub-functions (python)?

Tags: python, inspect

How do I use inspection to retrieve a list of sub-functions?

```
def f( x, y):

    def g( a ):
       return a + 1

    def h( z ):
       return b + 1

subs = inspect.getsubfunctions( f ) 
#Should return [ g, h ]
```

Comment: Interesting approach in the dupe, but it's prone to false positives. Lambdas, genexps, and classes all show up as code objects in the function's `func_code.co_consts`. It'll give decent results as a heuristic, still, especially for the asker's use case in the dupe.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The "subfunctions" don't exist until the function is called. Even once it's called, the `g` and `h` definitions create new, mostly-identical functions on each `f` call, so you can't get *the* `g` function or *the* `h` function.